# Divide contents of one hash with contents of another in Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

So i have 2 hashes created

```
total_spend = monthly_subscriptions_new.group_by_day(:created_at).sum(:total_spend)
total_subs = monthly_subscriptions_new.group_by_day(:created_at).count
```

the result is a hash with Date:value
e.g.
**total_spend**

Jan 1:300

Jan 2:400

Jan 3:500

and **total_subs**

Jan 1: 5

Jan 2: 6

Jan 3: 7

i want to divide the total spend value by the total count and represent it in a new hash

So i want a new hash with

Jan 1: 60

Jan 2 : 67

Jan 3: 71

etc.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to calculate the **average**? There's a direct method for that: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/average

Comment: is there an easy way to get that average straight into a hash like above then? - update: actually scrap that - that's perfect thank you it works on the group_by_day function as well

Comment: Presumably, you have hashes `total_spend = { 'Jan 1':300, 'Jan 2':400, 'Jan 3':500 }` and `total_subs = { 'Jan 1': 5, 'Jan 2': 6, 'Jan 3': 7 }`, and you wish to produce the hash `{ 'Jan 1': 60, 'Jan 2': 67, 'Jan 3': 71 }`. If so, you should write them like that, in part so that readers can cut-and-paste to demonstrate code. Moreover, the way in which `total_spend` and `total_subs` were computed is irrelevant to the question, so those two assignments at the beginning should be deleted.

Comment: Try `average = total_spend.merge(total_subs) { |_,spend,sub| spend.fdiv(sub).round } #=> {:"Jan 1"=>60, :"Jan 2"=>67, :"Jan 3"=>71}`. This uses the form of [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to compute the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which in this case is all keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#average`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average) like this:

```
daily_average = monthly_subscriptions_new.group_by_day(:created_at)
                                         .average(:total_spend)
```

Comment: Is `.map(&:round)` needed at  the end?

Comment: Good question, might be. Depends on the OPs needs. But I would argue that if the output should be rounded then that is a view dependency and I would do that in the view or in a helper.